# Nested Arrays in ASPjson

Tags: json, vbscript

Using https://www.aspjson.com/ to parse and write JSON

I have a structure of data on an organization.
One of these pieces of info is their physical locations. Each location can have multiple rooms.
But when I try write the code to create the rooms within each location item, I get an error: `Object required: 'JSON.data(...)`.

This is the code I have successfully written so far:

```
{
  "locations": [{
      "locationid": 524,
      "locationname": "test building"
    },
    {
      "locationid": 525,
      "locationname": " building 1"
    },
    {
      "locationid": 526,
      "locationname": "test building 2"
    },
    {
      "locationid": 527,
      "locationname": "test building 3"
    },
  ]
}
```

What I would like to do is create a “rooms” collection within each location item, much like this below, but I am getting the above error when trying to create the 2nd nested array of rooms. *(see my code below)*

```
    {
      "locationid": 527,
      "locationname": "test building 3",
      "rooms" :[
        {
          "roomid": 111,
          "roomname": "room 1 "
        },
        {
          "roomid": 222,
          "roomname": "room 2"
        },
      ]
    },

// additional locations follow ...
```

**My current code:**

```
          .Add "locations", JSON.Collection()
          With JSON.data("locations")

                 .Add 0, JSON.Collection()
                 With .item(0)
                       .Add "locationid", 111
                       .Add "locationname", "location 1"

                       .Add "rooms", JSON.Collection()
                       With JSON.data("rooms")  /// this is where I get the error. 

             .Add 0, JSON.Collection()
              With .item(0)
                  .Add "roomid",  1
                  .Add "roomname", "room1"
             end with 

             .Add 1, JSON.Collection()
              With .item(1)
                  .Add "roomid",  2
                  .Add "roomname", "room2"
              end with 



                       end with
                 end with
          
          end with
```

Comment: @Tomalak can’t say I’ve ever had problems using [aspjson](https://www.aspjson.com) personally.

Comment: @user692942 Well, one can make anything work. But given the fact that ASP Classic supports JScript out of the box (and side-by-side with VBScript blocks), and all that's missing is a JSON parser, which is easily added, I'd opt for a language which handles the data structures in JSON more naturally than VBScript does.

Comment: @Tomalak I wasn’t suggesting there is anything wrong with using JScript to parse JSON, just if you are more comfortable using VBScript I’ve not personally had any issues using [aspjson](https://www.aspjson.com) in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the structure of the objects `JSON.data("rooms")` will not exist because `JSON.data()` is reading from the root of the JSON structure. Once you add the `rooms` collection you need to work from that instance because the current `.Item` instance is the context where the `rooms` collection has been added. So the line should be;

```vb
With .Item("rooms")
```

Comment: Thank you. Now getting this error instead, on the same line: `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'data'`

Comment: @kneidels can you update the code in the question to reflect what you’ve tried?

Comment: apologies - my bad. your answer is correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer for your question, but food for thought.

Once you have included [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in your ASP page:

```asp
<script runat="server" language="JScript" src="json2.js"></script>
```

it's no longer necessary to bend over backwards to work with JSON; you literally only need to write it down.

```asp
<script runat="server" language="JScript">
var data = {
  "locations": [{
    "locationid": 526,
    "locationname": "test building 2"
  },
  {
    "locationid": 527,
    "locationname": "test building 3"
  }
]};

for (var i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {
  data.locations[i].rooms = {
    "rooms": [{
      "roomid": 111,
      "roomname": "room 1"
    },
    {
      "roomid": 222,
      "roomname": "room 2"
    }]
  };
}

Response.Write(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));    
</script>
```

JScript blocks and VBScript blocks can coexist on the same page. They even can call each other's functions. Do the things that are easy in JS syntax in JScript blocks, and things that are easy in VB syntax in VBScript blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - definitely worth considering!

Comment: If you are comfortable with JScript, this is definitely an alternative.

Comment: @user692942 If you're doing *any* kind of web development, chances are kind of ... high that you've worked with JavaScript before.

Comment: @user692942  I know. :) I wasn't arguing, those comments were half-way directed at the OP, really. Although... I don't know what it is, but something gives me the feeling that they are not really considering the approach.